# packets lost xbee series 1

Tags: raspberry-pi, xbee

I have two xbee's series 1. I have them as endpoint devices working in API mode and talking to each other. The first xbee is attached at a raspberry pi, while the other is on my pc where I see the terminal tab of XCTU program. The baud rate I use is 125000.

From raspberry pi I try to send a jpg image which is 30Kbytes. I send data frames 100 byte long (the biggest as it is said in the xbee documentation). Inside a loop I create and send the packets, I have also a `cout` statement that prints the loop number. Everything is fine and all bytes are sent. When I comment out the `cout` statement not all bytes are sent.

From what I have understood the `cout` statement works as a delay between packets, but I still cannot understand why is this happening as it is supposed that I use the half speed ...

I hope I was clear and look forward for a reply.

**UPDATE**
Just to summarize, i changed baud rate to 250000 where there is the same behavior as in 125000. I also implemented hardware flow control by checking cts signal. When xbees are in transparent mode I need a delay between sending characters at around 150us. The same goes for api mode too. The difference with 125000 baud rate in api mode was that the delay needed, was enough to be betwween each data packet, but in 250000 the delay is needed between each byte that i send.  If i do the above everything goes well.

The next thing i did was to plug both xbees in my pc in transparent mode. I went to terminal tab of xctu software where i chose assemble packet and sent at around 3000 bytes to the other xbee. The result was the same. The second xbee received at about 1500 bytes and then each time that i was sending one byte from the first to the second, the "lost bytes" were being received at packets of 1000. :/

So could anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should connect the /CTS pin from the XBee module into the Raspberry Pi, and have your routine stop sending data when the XBee de-asserts it.

At higher baud rates, it's possible to stream data into the XBee module faster than it can send to the remote module.  The local XBee module uses the /CTS pin to notify the host when its buffers are almost full and the host should stop sending.  People refer to this as hardware flow control.

It may be necessary to modify the serial driver on the Raspberry Pi to make use of that signal -- it should pause the transmit buffer when de-asserted, and automatically resume sending when re-asserted.

Comment: Since yesterday, I changed to Transparent mode(just to have simple messages) where I had the same exact problem. I implemented the CTS hardware flow control both in API and  Transparent mode but nothing changed.

In transparent mode I observed that after some bytes were sent and the XCTU terminal tab had stopped displaying received bytes (making me believe that the bytes were lost), I asked the xbee in rpi to  send me one character "a". With that character also came 1000 bytes that i thought lost, the second "a" the next 1000 etc. 
I cannot understand it at all :S..